# Python - replicating the GIMP's "Erase color" blend mode

Tags: python, opencv, colors, gimp, blend-mode

I'm looking for a way to recreate the GIMP's **Erase color** blending mode in Python 3 & OpenCV2.

I know it's possible to erase color using the that library, but the code I run works on exactly one of them. <s>Furthermore, I don't believe such small amount of code could do that advanced thing.</s>

Looking for a solution, I found the [`blend-modes`](https://github.com/flrs/blend_modes) by [`flrs`](https://github.com/flrs), but it also doesn't include the option I want.

---

Sadly, I have no experience in OpenCV2 at the moment, but I think developing such thing could be very helpful.

**Can someone guide me how to make this more reliable, or is it even possible to do with things that I've got already?**

---

## OpenCV2 color removal

### Code

```py
import cv2
from PIL import Image

#-=-=-=-#

File_Name = r"Spectrogram.png"
SRC = cv2.imread(File_Name, 1)
TMP = cv2.cvtColor(SRC, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, A = cv2.threshold(TMP, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
B, G, R = cv2.split(SRC)
Colors = [B, G, R, A]
Picture = cv2.merge(Colors, 4)

#-=-=-=-#

# My CV2 image display doesn't include transparency
im = cv2.cvtColor(Picture, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
im = Image.fromarray(im)

im.show()
```

### Result

| Original | Result |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

---

## GIMP *Erase color* blending-mode

| Type | Background | Foreground | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Image | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| Blending | Normal | Erase color | Normal |

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just use GIMP? It has a scripting interface...

Comment: GIMP is clearly not using binary thresholding, look at the upper corners that are mostly red.

Comment: @MattDMo I'll sound pretty selfish - because I can't use it and I'm more familiar with Python.
Also, GIMP is not as portable as Python is.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple way in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Choose a color range
- Apply range to threshold the image
- Invert the range as a mask to be used later for the alpha channel
- Convert the image from BGR to BGRA
- Put mask into the alpha channel of the BGRA image
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image and set the bounds
img = cv2.imread("red_black.png")

# choose color range
lower =(0,0,0) # lower bound for each BGR channel
upper = (140,0,190) # upper bound for each BRG channel

# create the mask
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# invert mask
mask = 255 - mask

# convert image to BGRA
result = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

# put mask into alpha channel
result[:,:,3] = mask

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("red_black_color_removed.png", result)

# display it (though does not display transparency properly)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("results", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Pretty good approach, but can I decrease the _blockiness_?